# No constructor with 0 arguments defined in class when explicitly define constructor

Tags: java, spring, constructor

I don't understand...  I actually defined constructor but I am getting

`No constructor with 0 arguments defined in class`

```
@Component
public class CustomMessageSource extends ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource {

public CustomMessageSource(Locale locale){

    this.propertiesHolder = getMergedProperties(locale);        

    this.properties = propertiesHolder.getProperties();
}
//... other setting, getters
```

This is how I instantiated it

`CustomMessageSource customMessage = new CustomMessageSource(locale);`

This is my stack trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.app.service.CustomMessageSource.<init>()
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3074)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2170)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
... 38 more
```

Comment: Your constructor has `1` argument, not `0`. If you want an `0` argument constructor and you defined at least one constructor, you need to write a `0` argument constructor yourself. Java will provide a `0` argument constructor (default-constructor), if and only if you did not write any constructor at all.

Comment: @Turing85 Right but adding a no arg constructor doesn't seem suitable since it will prevent from creating a `CustomMessageSource` instance with a consistent state guaranteed by the constructor with arg that is defined.

Comment: Put `@Autowired` on the constructor (or use Spring 4.3) to tell spring which one to use, else it expects a default no-args constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Spring wants to instantiate the no arg constructor by reflection :

```
 com.app.service.CustomMessageSource.<init>()
```

By specifying `@Autowired` in the constructor, it should work :

```
@Autowired
public CustomMessageSource(Locale locale){
```

If you use Spring 4.3 or later, beans declared with a single constructor don't need to specify the `@Autowired` annotation.
Source : https://spring.io/blog/2016/03/04/core-container-refinements-in-spring-framework-4-3

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can define multiple constructors. By default if you want to add a constructor with parameters, you have to define the parameterless constructor first. 
So your code will look like:

```
@Component
public class CustomMessageSource extends ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource {

        public CustomMessageSource() {} 
        public CustomMessageSource(Locale locale){

            this.propertiesHolder = getMergedProperties(locale);        

            this.properties = propertiesHolder.getProperties();
        }
       //... other setting, getters
}
```